# AWS Athena JSON format failure

Tags: json, amazon-athena

I am trying to upload the data from this json:

**JSON-A**

```
[
  {"name": "james", "id": 41},
  {"name": "scott", "id": 62},
  {"name": "abhi", "id": 16},
  {"name": "kevin", "id": 53},
  {"name": "beau", "id": 12},
  {"name": "shally", "id": 35},
  {"name": "jude", "id": 53},
  {"name": "jason", "id": 77},
  {"name": "hongjian", "id": 35},
  {"name": "madhur", "id": 6}
]
```

If it had the parent "data" key like

**JSON-B**

```
["data":{"name": "james","id": 41"},{.....}]
```

then I know I can do like :

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.test (
  `data` array<struct<`name`:string,`id`:bigint>>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'serialization.format' = '1'
) LOCATION 's3://test-bucket/';
```

But what should be the way to do for JSON-A?

Comment: JSON-A meant to represent a single cell in your table? because this is what your create statement does

Comment: thats what I do not want. I want every element as different cells in table and not able to figure out how. Can't come up with a create statement for JSON-A.

Answer (score 5):

I do not think this will work, because of the Hive/SerDe assumption that your text file contain one record per line.  From the [org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe documentation](https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde):

1. [One Record Per Line](https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde#jsonserde---a-readwrite-serde-for-json-data) - although I'm not sure your sample is meant to be literal in the multiline respect, the sample does contain multiple records in the same line.

> IMPORTANT!!! READ THIS BELOW!! Json records must be one per line, that is, the serde WILL NOT WORK with multiline Json.

2. [Array Examples One-per-Line](https://github.com/rcongiu/Hive-JSON-Serde#support-for-arrays) - the serde examples do show how to work with arrays, but again, not a top-level array encompassing multiple records in the same line.

Answer (score 5):

You will have to hold a file in 's3://test-bucket/':
`{"name": "james", "id": 41}
    {"name": "scott", "id": 62}
    {"name": "abhi", "id": 16}
    {"name": "kevin", "id": 53}
    {"name": "beau", "id": 12}
    {"name": "shally", "id": 35}
    {"name": "jude", "id": 53}
    {"name": "jason", "id": 77}
    {"name": "hongjian", "id": 35}
    {"name": "madhur", "id": 6}`